# PHP converting object to string

Tags: php, string, object

I'm planning to save a returned object to a file, for downloading later on to review.
For clarity sake, I'm working with an outside API service, and gathering their data, for parsing into another database.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
require('class.php');
$client = new connect2Them();
$logged_in = $client->login();
if(!$logged_in){
  echo "Not connected!"; die();
}

$records = $client->get_records();
if(count($records < 1){
  echo "No records found"; die();
}

$singlerecord = $records[0];
print_r($singlerecord);

?>
```

The print_r() works fine, and I get back a very very large amount of data.  I'm doing all this via command-line, so I want to save it to a text file.

I've added this below my $singlerecord:

```
<?php
$myFile = "reviewLater.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $singlerecord;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

I get this error from PHP:
**PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in....**

How do I put the print_r() into the reviewLater.txt?

Comment: Are you trying to store the data for later programmatic use, or just for human reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said above, you can serialize(), but to answer your question:

> How do I put the print_r() into the reviewLater.txt?

If you set the second parameter of `print_r()` to true, there will be a string of the output and you can manipulate it as such :)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  And yet so simple

Answer (score 6):

Objects can be serialized with PHP's `serialize()` function and saved to a file. Later you can  `unserialize()` them to use them again if you want.

```
$stringData = serialize($singlerecord);
```

Fun Fact: This is one way to cache objects to files.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Well there is [`var_export`](http://se.php.net/manual/de/function.var-export.php).

Comment: There is actually many ways to do this, and it all depends on the use case. Thanks, for adding that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with simple objects (eg. not objects that reference themselves or are custom classes), you can use `json_encode` to encode the object to a JSON and `json_decode` to decode it later.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php.

Answer (score 0):

Since The question about a means to serialize the data for later programmatic use has been given, I will mention that if you are just concerned about human-readable output, you can use `fwrite($fh, var_export($singlerecord, true));` to print human readable representation as string output.